# JMeter unable to fetch redirect url

Tags: url, redirect, jmeter

my URL(https://www.test.com) has parameters
response_type,client_id,redirect_uri:https://wwwx.dummy.com, scope

When I paste my URL with params in chrome, I get the redirect URL as 
https://wwwx.dummy.com?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

But  in Jmeter I am unable to get this code parameter

1. Enabled debug post processor
2. capturing regular expression from URL (.*)
3. trying to post the redirect url in next http request

I dont see redirect url in any of the sub samples.

kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a 3rd-party website you can use a local address like `http://localhost:8081/foo/bar` as the **redirect_uri** so the request will go to your local JMeter instance instead of the remote website.

You can extract the code from the request's [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)

If you don't want the sampler to fail you can use i.e. [HTTP Mirror Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Mirror_Server) in order to "catch" the request.